# Nature "Communications Arising" how recent must the original article be?

Tags: publications

Nature's [guidelines for authors](http://www.nature.com/nature/authors/gta/commsarising.html) say that

> Critical comments on recent Nature papers may, after peer review, be published online as Brief Communications Arising

What actually counts as *recent* in this case? One year? Five years? It would be helpful to know before initiating the communications arising process which begins with direct correspondence to the author of the original paper, so carries consequences which may not be worthwhile if Nature consider the original paper too old to be of note.

Comment: This seems like a question for Nature, not for Academia S.E.

Comment: You might just ask the editor if a comment to a specific publication is still "in time".

Comment: I'm interested in the answer. Did you ask Nature, @SideshowBob?

Comment: Yes, eventually. Without naming the paper I said it was 5 years old and they said that is recent enough to consider a BCA.

Comment: @SideshowBob Thanks for your contribution. Did you eventually submit the BCA?

Comment: Never did; I decided to incorporate the criticism into another paper (which hasn't seen the light of day yet)